# Will rosjava be supported on Lunar and future releases?

Tags: ros, web, rosjava, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found some articles on REST services using rosjava and would like to know the feasibility of this using the latest ROS releases and latest Ubuntu releases.

Per http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava, Lunar does not support rosjava. Will this be the same for future releases? If rosjava is no longer supported, are there examples for roscpp to support REST services?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263709/will-rosjava-be-supported-on-lunar-and-future-releases?/) by [coolbeans](https://answers.ros.org/users/30731/coolbeans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@coolbeans if you want to try those REST services in Lunar / Ubuntu 17, I'd try using rosjava from source: http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/Source%20Installation. As far as I understand, it should work -perhaps you will need to rebuild some messages if the version changes from Kinetic to Lunar, or similar compatibility issues-.

Supporting Lunar is not in the roadmap, but the next release associated with a LTS version might be supported in the future.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0